# Google Chrome not loading any webpages, meanwhile FireFox and other internet based services work just fine

Tags: google-chrome, internet

I've encountered a strange problem. Yesterday my Google Chrome browser was working just fine, but today it won't load any webpages. It seems like it is cut off from the internet completely, because I cannot even send an automatic report to Google. I'm not a super user of Linux so I'm having trouble solving it alone. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and Google Chrome version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I'm not using any kind of firewalls, antiviruses, etc.

Comment: You can try to start Chrome from the command line without plugins or extensions: `chrome  --disable-extensions --disable-plugins`

Comment: I have the same weird problem today. Ping and Firefox work fine, but Google can't resolve anything.

Comment: Do you find solution?

Comment: Running from the terminal using `google-chrome` seems to work ...